# SassError: Can't find stylesheet to import after update from Vue2.6 to Vue2.7

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-test-utils, sass-loader

I've got a bunch of errors after the update from Vue 2.6(2.6.11) to Vue 2.7 (2.7.13):

> Error in
>
> ./src/views/pages/SupportPage.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=43fb95c5&lang=scss&scoped=true&
>
> Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
>
> SassError: Can't find stylesheet to import.
>
> ```
> ╷   1 │ @import "@/assets/styles/variables.scss";
> │         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> ╵
>
> [path to the project]\src\views\pages\SupportPage.vue 1:9  root stylesheet
> ```

---

### Folders structure:

[image: Folders structure]

---

### tests/unit/setup.js:

```
import '@/components/global-components'
import sinon from 'sinon'
import localStorage from './test-helpers/local-storage'

global.sinon = sinon
global.localStorage = localStorage

window.HTMLElement.prototype.scrollIntoView = () => {}
window.matchMedia = window.matchMedia || function matchMedia () {
  return {
    matches: false,
    addListener () {},
    removeListener () {}
  }
}
```

### Pre-Processor Loader in *vue.config.js*:

```
css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      sass: {
        prependData: '@import "@/assets/styles/variables.scss";'
      }
    }
  }
```

---

### package.json:

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "test:unit": "vue-cli-service test:unit --include tests/unit/setup.js --timeout 5000",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint --no-fix",
    "deploy": "vue-cli-service s3-deploy",
    "lint:fix": "vue-cli-service lint --fix",
    "test": "yarn test:unit",
    "cy:open": "cypress open",
    "cy:run": "cypress run",
    "cy:test": "start-server-and-test serve http://localhost:8080 'yarn cy:run --record --headless --browser chrome'",
    "recache": "node ./public/scripts/recache.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@appsignal/javascript": "^1.0.0",
    "@appsignal/vue": "^1.0.0",
    "@contentful/rich-text-from-markdown": "^13.4.0",
    "@contentful/rich-text-html-renderer": "^13.0.0",
    "@contentful/rich-text-types": "^15.7.0",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.4.0",
    "actioncable": "^5.2.2",
    "apollo-cache-inmemory": "^1.6.6",
    "apollo-client": "^2.6.10",
    "apollo-link": "^1.2.14",
    "apollo-link-error": "^1.1.13",
    "apollo-link-http": "^1.5.17",
    "apollo-utilities": "^1.3.4",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "body-scroll-lock": "^3.1.3",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "bootstrap-vue": "^2.22.0",
    "contentful": "^7.3.0",
    "contentful-rich-text-vue-renderer": "^2.1.0",
    "core-js": "^3.6.4",
    "countries-list": "^2.4.2",
    "graphql": "^15.0.0",
    "graphql-ruby-client": "1.7.4",
    "graphql-tag": "^2.9.2",
    "gsap": "./gsap-bonus.tgz",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "logrocket": "^2.1.3",
    "mobile-detect": "^1.4.4",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.33",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.3",
    "paymentiq-cashier-bootstrapper": "^1.3.2",
    "qrcode": "^1.3.4",
    "smoothscroll-polyfill": "^0.4.4",
    "sourcebuster": "^1.1.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "text-mask-addons": "^3.8.0",
    "throttle-debounce": "^3.0.1",
    "unfetch": "^3.1.1",
    "vue": "^2.7.13",
    "vue-apollo": "^3.0.0-beta.19",
    "vue-clipboard2": "^0.3.0",
    "vue-i18n": "^8.10.0",
    "vue-lazyload": "^1.3.3",
    "vue-meta": "^2.0.4",
    "vue-mq": "^1.0.1",
    "vue-observe-visibility": "^0.4.6",
    "vue-radial-progress": "^0.3.2",
    "vue-recaptcha": "^1.1.1",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.1",
    "vue-text-mask": "^6.1.2",
    "vue-visibility-change": "^1.2.1",
    "vuejs-datepicker": "^1.6.2",
    "vuejs-logger": "^1.5.3",
    "vuelidate": "^0.7.5",
    "vuex": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-optional-chaining": "^7.8.3",
    "@vue/cli": "^4.5.19",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^4.5.19",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^4.5.19",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-mocha": "^4.5.19",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^4.5.19",
    "@vue/eslint-config-airbnb": "^5.0.2",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^1.0.3",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "chai": "^4.1.2",
    "compression-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "cypress": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint": "7.2.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "14.2.1",
    "eslint-loader": "^2.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-cypress": "^2.11.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.7.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.3.0",
    "moment-locales-webpack-plugin": "^1.2.0",
    "preload-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0-beta.4",
    "sass": "^1.26.5",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "sinon": "^6.1.4",
    "sinon-chai": "^3.2.0",
    "standard": "^12.0.1",
    "start-server-and-test": "^1.11.3",
    "vue-cli-plugin-s3-deploy": "~4.0.0-rc3",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.7.14",
    "webfonts-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "webpack": "^4.0.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.8.0"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 8"
  ],
  "resolutions": {
    "@babel/parser": "7.20.2"
  }
}
```

---

### Changes after the update (package.json):

[image: Changes after the update]
[image: Changes after the update]

Comment: Try with `"sass": "1.32.8", "sass-loader": "^10.1.0",` in your `package.json`, remove `style-loader`, update `"eslint": "^7.32.0"`, delete `node_modules` and run `npm install`

Comment: Updating the libraries above did not help. The same error

Comment: This is strange, because the new SASS-loader should have complained about the old configuration in `vue.config.js` - specifically, it should complain about `prependData` not being recognized and suggesting `additionalData` instead. By the way, why do you place it under `loaderOptions.sass` instead of `loaderOptions.scss` ?

Comment: yes I changed to additionalData  at once, but it did not help

Comment: > By the way, why do you place it under loaderOptions.sass instead of loaderOptions.scss ?
---

it wasn't my decision, I've started working on the project with the configuration

Comment: I can think of only 2 possible causes - either the specified file does not exist or the `@` alias does not exist (or points to the wrong folder). If you have already checked and confirmed none of these is true - I am out of ideas.